# Firebase query to get same appointment time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a real-time firebase database, where I saved appointment timing for multiple vendors. For example, in each location/area I have 4 vendors so per hours 4 bookings can be made each for single vendors like 11 am can be booked 4 times, and so on, and vendors are registered as normal email password registration using the flutter app. This is how my vendor list looks like

[image]

Now whenever someone books an appointment this is how I save appointment timing for a single vendor and it's the same way for other vendors too just timing might be different based on booking time, I added my code too, If I'm doing wrong please suggest me correct way too

[image]

```
DatabaseReference providerBookingRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
          .reference()
          .child('availableProviderList/${provider}/bookingTime/')
          .push();
      
providerBookingRef.set(availableTimeSlotsFm[0]['availableTimeSlotsFormatted']
          .toString());
```

Now what I want to check is query each vendor and check if all vendors are booked for the same time or not so I got the length of vendors and check at the particular time say 11 am all vendors are booked or someone is available. I don't know how to query this logic or I might be saving appointments timing wrong??

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: Also: how is this different from the problem you posted yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67305229/not-able-to-filter-date-and-time-from-the-list-coming-from-firebase-database. If you want to clarify that problem, please edit there - and don't post a new question for the same problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your response, I'll change my yesterday question as I have been looking for the answer for quite some time and didn't get any response.

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen is there a way I can just read the all value of bookingTime one by one without adding the value say `-MZS10sSRSBrSi8Nbzqf` just it's value or do I have to rename it something else??